# Binding from usercontrol to property of parent usercontrol

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, user-controls, parent

Let's say I have a user control called Graph in a window. This user control contains a grid, within which there is another user control, called Toolbar. Now Graph exposes a public property called Mode, which uses a dependency property called ModeProperty as a backing store. I want an element in the Toolbar user control to bind to the Mode property in its ancestor Graph. How can I do this? Even just getting a reference to Graph is proving to be harder than I expected, this.parent gets a reference to the grid rather than the Graph.

Answer (score 7):

You can bind it in xaml only like this -

```
<Toolbar Mode="{Binding Path=Mode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource
      Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType = UserControl, AncestorLevel =2}}"/>
```

Also you can use the ElementName in your binding like this -

```
<Toolbar Mode="{Binding Path=Mode, ElementName=GraphUserControl}"/>
```

You have to set x:Name property on your userControl to which you want to bind to -

```
<UserControl x:Name="GraphUserControl"></UserControl>
```

Or in case you won't to do in code behind, you can look at this useful post for travelling to ancestor parent - [Visual Tree Navigator](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/)

Comment: That's what I've been trying, but problem is I'm applying the binding on a checkbox within the toolbar rather than the toolbar itself. I can't specify the actual type of user control, so the ancestor it gets is the immediate one (toolbar), when the one I want is graph. Is there any way to specify that I want an ancestor 2 levels up, or of the specific type Graph, rather than just the generic usercontrol?

Comment: Yeah you can specify the ancestor level in your relative source markup extension. See my edited answer.

Comment: Ah nice! I worked around this temporarily by just having the Graph set a property in the toolbar that elements within toolbar could then bind to, but that's obviously not ideal, will try this solution out. Also, Graph is the Class name, not the element name, so there can be multiple graphs open simultaneously. No way to specify which class name you want, right?

Comment: x:Class and x:Name are entirely different things. You have to set x:Name on your userControl and then you can bind it using ElementName. See my updated answer. And doesn't specifying AncestorLevel works for you?